# jQuery UI dialog doesn't work in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI Dialog to display a window on my application. This window displays correctly in IE7, IE8, FF and chorme, but doesn't works fine on IE9. When I click at link that should open the dialog, nothing happens.

Anyone can help me?

```
$('#open_chat').click(function() {
  $('#chat').dialog({
    width: 422,
    resizable: false,
    title: '<img align="absmiddle" src="/img/icone_chat.png"> Chat <span>(clique e arraste para movimentar)</span>'
  });
  return false;
})
```

Comment: We might need to see the code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Edit the code into your original question. Comments are not the place for more than the briefest of code samples.

Answer (score 5):

While initial investigation seems to point to an issue somewhere in jQuery or jQuery UI, this actually turns out to be an issue in the jQuery plugin called "bgiframe."  This is a known issue with bgiframe and was fixed with version 2.1.2.  It's mentioned in [this jQuery UI Ticket (#6190)](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6190).

We had a page that uses the jQuery UI Dialog module, and we were experiencing some very odd behavior only in IE9.  We narrowed it down to the code that initializes the dialog (and then we found the ticket referenced above).  After updating the bgiframe plugin to 2.1.2, the issues are resolved in IE9.

You should be able to find the [latest version of bgiframe on the github download page](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/downloads) for the project.  When I wrote this answer, the latest version was 2.1.2.